# Add small button on the upper right of imageview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview

Currently i have this layout:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/96ANL.jpg

this is the code for this layout:

```
  <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <HorizontalScrollView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/img_docu_placeholder"/>


                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/img_docu_placeholder"/>
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/img_docu_placeholder"/>
                            <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/img_docu_placeholder"/>
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/img_docu_placeholder"/>

                        </LinearLayout>
                        </FrameLayout>

                    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

What i'm trying to achieve is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg6aE.jpg

where i need to add additional 'X' button on the upper left side of the imageview

Comment: If my answer fits for you, please accept it

Comment: The x button becomes out of bounds when i add picture in the imageview

Comment: @PhátPhát would it possible to do it using coordinatelayout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FrameLayout`. Your icon must have `android:layout_gravity` attribute.

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgX"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left" //This line
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: will this be able to adjust in different screen sizes?

Comment: You can use sdp library to make responsive desing.

Comment: would it possible to do it using coordinatelayout?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="108dp"
android:background="#ffffff">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="#e6e6e6" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="16dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel_black" />
```

Output:

[image]

Support multiple resolution:

- Using this library: https://github.com/intuit/sdp
- Create multiple layouts for each screen and using `dp`